# Jquery Auto complete not appearing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I had it working before, but it's not now, I have no idea why, can someone take a look and let me know?

http://www.davemartineau.com/Toronto/

The Search box should auto complete, start with "T" and tim hortons should auto complete.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a "please fix this for me" site. Please edit your question explaining what you have tried, and post meaningful code here.

Comment: I would try firebug (Firefox Addon) and wrap the code in a try catch statement, outputting any caught errors to the firebug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a jQuery exception occurring in jquery.ui.draggable.js.  Did you change the jquery version or did you not use the one supplied with jqueryUI?

The exception was "Cannot call method 'autocomplete' of null".

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827830/jqueryui-uncaught-exception-cannot-call-methods) but I don't think this is your issue.

Comment: Thank you! I'd been combining several javascripts and thought i was using jquery-1.5.1.min.js when i should have been using jquery-1.5.1.js (no "min")

Comment: Hmm the minified version should work.  Is that what came with your download of jQueryUi?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a type to the input:

```
<input type="text" id="search_text" value="" name="search"/>
```

Hope this helps!